# How to interpret the following pattern of uptime data?

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, mysql, troubleshooting

I have a small web server running mysql and wordpress which after a while appears to stop processing web requests. I can't even log into the server via ssh as ssh client times out when trying to establish the connection, with the only way to bring back the server is to do a hard reboot.

I left `ssh` running with `top` over a period of 10 hours to watch this server slowly die, and when it got to the point where there it appear stuck top was still working. I was able to quit `top` shut down `mysql` and `httpd` then repeatedly typed `uptime` and the load average went from `101.73` to `0.01` in the span of 10 minutes after shutting down `httpd` and `mysqld`.

I have provided data I was able to collect below.

**My Questions:**

- what is the meaning of the data?
- Is this machine out of CPU or RAM?
- Would a bigger box solve the problem?
- What other tools can be used to identify the cause of this problem.

**Here is a snapshot of `top` just before I quit it and shutdown `httpd` and `mysqld`**

```
top - 11:00:18 up 13:54,  1 user,  load average: 96.13, 94.78, 90.06
Tasks: 173 total,   1 running, 172 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.5%us,  1.1%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 98.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1016284k total,  1008232k used,     8052k free,      580k buffers
Swap:  2096440k total,  2095168k used,     1272k free,     9872k cached

 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                          
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.2  0.0   0:09.98 events/0                                                                                          
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.1  0.0   0:11.66 kblockd/0                                                                                         
 1267 root      20   0  114m  316  232 S  0.1  0.0   0:00.41 crond         

 4779 apache    20   0  270m  11m  548 D  0.1  1.2   0:00.68 httpd                                                                                             
 4878 apache    20   0  261m  17m  896 D  0.1  1.8   0:00.44 httpd                                                                                             
 5046 apache    20   0  272m  19m 1168 D  0.1  1.9   0:00.69 httpd                                                                                             
 5258 apache    20   0  244m 2552 1300 D  0.1  0.3   0:00.01 httpd  
 ...... stuff I have removed to make this list short  
1532 root      20   0  105m    4    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 mysqld_safe                                                                                       
 1634 mysql     20   0  713m 8656 1612 S  0.0  0.9   1:13.79 mysqld                                                                                            
 1805 root      20   0  244m  976   80 S  0.0  0.1   0:03.43 httpd
```

**Data from the `uptime` command**

```
 11:01:50 up 13:55,  1 user,  load average: 99.15, 95.94, 90.88
 11:05:19 up 13:59,  2 users,  load average: 101.73, 97.93, 92.65
 11:05:45 up 13:59,  2 users,  load average: 67.02, 90.07, 90.18
 11:07:27 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 11.61, 63.36, 80.53
 11:07:30 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 11.61, 63.36, 80.53
 11:07:35 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 10.68, 62.31, 80.10
 11:07:39 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 9.83, 61.28, 79.67
 11:07:41 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 9.04, 60.26, 79.24
 11:07:43 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 9.04, 60.26, 79.24
 11:07:48 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 8.31, 59.26, 78.82
 11:07:50 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 8.31, 59.26, 78.82
 11:07:52 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 7.65, 58.28, 78.39
 11:07:54 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 7.65, 58.28, 78.39
 11:07:56 up 14:01,  2 users,  load average: 7.65, 58.28, 78.39
 11:07:57 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 7.04, 57.31, 77.97
 11:07:58 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 7.04, 57.31, 77.97
 11:08:04 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 6.47, 56.36, 77.55
 11:08:05 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 6.47, 56.36, 77.55
 11:08:06 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.95, 55.42, 77.14
 11:08:08 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.95, 55.42, 77.14
 11:08:09 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.95, 55.42, 77.14
 11:08:10 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.95, 55.42, 77.14
 11:08:11 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.48, 54.50, 76.72
 11:08:12 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.48, 54.50, 76.72
 11:08:14 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.48, 54.50, 76.72
 11:08:15 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.48, 54.50, 76.72
 11:08:16 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.04, 53.60, 76.31
 11:08:17 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.04, 53.60, 76.31
 11:08:19 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.04, 53.60, 76.31
 11:08:20 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 5.04, 53.60, 76.31
 11:08:22 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 4.63, 52.70, 75.90
 11:08:23 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 4.63, 52.70, 75.90
 11:08:25 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 4.63, 52.70, 75.90
 11:08:26 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 4.26, 51.83, 75.49
 11:08:27 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 4.26, 51.83, 75.49
 11:08:28 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 4.26, 51.83, 75.49
 11:08:29 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 4.26, 51.83, 75.49
 11:08:33 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 3.92, 50.97, 75.09
 11:08:36 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 3.61, 50.12, 74.68
 11:08:38 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 3.61, 50.12, 74.68
 11:08:40 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 3.61, 50.12, 74.68
 11:08:41 up 14:02,  2 users,  load average: 3.32, 49.29, 74.28
 11:09:11 up 14:03,  2 users,  load average: 2.01, 44.58, 71.92
 11:09:13 up 14:03,  2 users,  load average: 2.01, 44.58, 71.92
 11:09:24 up 14:03,  2 users,  load average: 1.70, 43.11, 71.15
 11:09:25 up 14:03,  2 users,  load average: 1.70, 43.11, 71.15
 11:10:41 up 14:04,  2 users,  load average: 0.48, 33.53, 65.62
 11:10:43 up 14:04,  2 users,  load average: 0.44, 32.98, 65.27
 11:10:53 up 14:04,  2 users,  load average: 0.38, 31.89, 64.57
 11:10:55 up 14:04,  2 users,  load average: 0.38, 31.89, 64.57
 11:11:38 up 14:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.18, 27.43, 61.51
 11:11:40 up 14:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.18, 27.43, 61.51
 11:11:41 up 14:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.18, 27.43, 61.51
 11:11:41 up 14:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 26.97, 61.18
 11:11:42 up 14:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 26.97, 61.18
 11:11:43 up 14:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 26.97, 61.18
 11:11:45 up 14:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 26.97, 61.18
 11:12:06 up 14:06,  2 users,  load average: 0.10, 24.80, 59.56
 11:12:10 up 14:06,  2 users,  load average: 0.10, 24.80, 59.56
 11:14:30 up 14:08,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 15.52, 51.21
 11:14:37 up 14:08,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 15.00, 50.66
```

Answer (score 5):

If you look at these lines in your `top` output:

```
Mem:   1016284k total,  1008232k used,     8052k free,      580k buffers
Swap:  2096440k total,  2095168k used,     1272k free,     9872k cached
```

you've run out of both RAM and swap. I suspect if you watch `vmstat 10` output, you'll see the machine is dying from thrashing.

A machine running MySQL and Apache should have almost no swap usage. I suspect you need to change your MySQL settings to match available memory (e.g., less query cache, smaller innodb pool, etc.). It's also possible you need to lower the maximum number of permitted Apache children. Or maybe you have a runaway script (PHP, etc.) that is using tons of memory (sort your top by RSS).

Comment: what does sort your top by RSS mean?

Comment: @ams RSS = resident set size. Basically the amount of RAM used (not swap). It's one of the sort options in top (and you can add it to the field list if it's not already there... f is the key binding if I remember correctly.)